# Right function Syntax in Excel

Tags: excel

From the syntax where we are supposed to enter second argument as a number . My input keeps on varying so how can I specify the second argument as "n" number of characters? Example input is 360 Secure Browser. I want excel to take the number of characters to be displayed from right on its own.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `RIGHT`,`FIND`,`LEN`.

For example, if you want to return "Secure Browser" you need to find the first space using `FIND`:
`=FIND(" ","360 Secure Browser")` which will return 4 - the first space is the fourth character.

Remove this value from the total length of the string:
`=LEN("360 Secure Browser")` returns the total length of 18.

`=LEN("360 Secure Browser")-FIND(" ","360 Secure Browser")`

18-4 = 14.  You're after the last fourteen characters in the text string.
`=RIGHT("360 Secure Browser",LEN("360 Secure Browser")-FIND(" ","360 Secure Browser"))`
or if you're text is in cell A1:
`=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1))`